I need the Script to push notification to my telegram
I have this code that is not working. I dont know why google app script keep displaying
This error:
when running function sendToTelegram
ReferenceError: cellValues is not defined
sendTelegramMessage
@ Code.gs:113
and when running function onEdit it appear
Error in onEdit: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')
but it still can run.
how can i run it with telegram working can anyone help?
my code
Without telegram function my code runs well, but when telegram function added. it has all sort of errors. `
